# Nosetest Generator Method Behavior

Tags: python, generator, nosetests

I am trying to write a test class that includes a generator and run the test with `nosetests`. However, I am confused by the way the `nosetests` test runner seems to isolate the methods in the test class so they do not share the same `self`:

```
class Test(object):

    def check(self):
        print self.one

    def test(self):
        self.one = 1
        yield self.check
```

This gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'one'
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with nose isolating the tests from one another is some way. Is there some work-around other than passing all the required variables to the method explicitly instead of implicitly as attributes on `self`?

To be clear, I know how to assign attributes in "standard" Python. That's not what I'm asking. What I want to know is how can I achieve the desired behavior in a `nosetests` test run with the `nosetests` command.

---

Per [Tanveer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3270800/tanveer-alam) suggestion I could add an `__init__` method to initialize the attribute. This is a work-around but it does answer my question as I originally posed it.

However, what I ultimately want to do it loop over the yield statement, modifying the value of the attribute on `self` and having that modification register in the value of `self` in the `check` method. Adding an `__init__` doesn't allow me to do that.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.one = None

    def check(self):
        print self.one

    def test(self):
        self.one = 1
        yield self.check
```

I get:

```
$ nosetests nosetest-with-classes.py --nocapture
None
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

There still seems to be some type of method-level isolation being enforced by the nosetests runner. So I'd like to dig a little deeper to understand what's going on. Is there a way to share attributes on the `self` variable in the normal way?

Comment: You can include `__init__` method and initialize your instance with `one` as argument to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot pass state using instance variables of the class. Upon hitting yield for class methods, nose will always figure out which class the method belongs to and will create a new instance of this class that will have no attributes that you tend to set on the current test generation class instance (see [nose lines that actually do that](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/case.py#L344)). One solution might be to use class variables to pass the information you want, something like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def check(self):
        print self.one # here it really refers to Test.one

    def test(self):
        Test.one = 1
        yield self.check
```

But I will suggest looking into [nose-parameterized plugin](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized), it does some of the magic you are trying to achieve here.